# Can I use = for the condition in for loops?

Tags: arrays

I am trying to make a program on a website that helps you learn coding (codehs) I am trying to make a program that adds one until it equals the actual passcode. I am a newbie, so I may be doing things wrong, but I don't want it to continue until it is less than my variable. I want to do it until it equals it.

I'm just unsure if this will work.

```
function start() {
    var secretPasscode = generateRandomPasscode();
    var count = 0;
    var guessed = 0000;
    for(i = 0; i = secretpasscode; i++){
      guessed += 1;  
      count++;
    } 
}
```

Will it work like this? I want it to continue until it equals that variable.

Comment: use `while` loop instead of `for`

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using JS for this.

```js
function start() {
  var secretPasscode = generateRandomPasscode();
  var guessed;
  for(guessed = 0; guessed != secretpasscode; guessed ++);

  console.log(guessed);

}
```

You get your random number from the function `generateRandomPasscode`. You define your `guessed`variable outside the `for` loop so that we can access it later on. Started counting from 0 because you want to know actual number of how many times the loop iterated. Using `console.log(guessed)` you can check the number of iterations it took to reach the answer.

On the other hand you can do this which will give you the same answer :

```js
function start() {
  console.log(generateRandomPasscode());
}
```

Because the loop that you are trying to make will always be equal to the number that is returned by your `generateRandomPasscode()`